# Mybatis, Enclosed OR with SQL builder

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, ibatis

I cannot figure out how to get MyBatis to generate an enclosed or statement:

```
WHERE x.token = ? AND (
  (x.scene = 'A' OR x.scene = 'B'))
```

This is a surprisingly simple operation they've made very difficult. I can't find it in the JavaDoc: http://static.javadoc.io/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.4.5/org/apache/ibatis/jdbc/SQL.html

Comment: missing end paren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done in the current version of mybatis (3.4.6).

You can either use the whole subexpression like this:

```
WHERE("x.token = ?");
WHERE("(x.scene = 'A' OR x.scene = 'B')");
```

or create you own function if you have many/variable number of operands to `OR`:

```
WHERE("x.token = ?");
WHERE(OR("x.scene = 'A'", "x.scene = 'B'"));
```

Where `OR` is defined (using [guava Joiner](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained)) as:

```
Joiner OR_JOINER = Joiner.on(" OR ");

private String OR(String ... operands) {
    return String.format("(%s)", OR_JOINER.join(operands));
}
```